# How to avoid adding duplicate entries in an arraylist of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class 'Employee' which has attributes (Designation, DoB, Employee-I'd, Name, Salary).

Now through the following function I'm adding 'n' employee objects in the ArrayList 'abc'

But I need to modify it in such a way that if an end user tries to add a duplicate employee (If name of two employees are same then it should be considered as duplicate) then the user is not allowed to do so...

How can I do this... I think probably using Map Interface... But no idea, how to implement

```
public void addEmployees(int n, ArrayList<Employee> abc)    /* 'n' is the number of employees to be added */
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee[] obj = new Employee[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            System.out.println("Enter Employee name:");
            String nm=sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter designation:");
            String des = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter employeeI-D:");
            int eId = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter salary:");
            double sl = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter date-of-birth:");
            String dt=sc.next();
            obj[i]=new Employee(des,dt,eId,nm,sl);
            abc.add(obj[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: does it have to be an `ArrayList`? Can't you use a `Set`?

Comment: Take a look at LinkedHashSet if you need to preserve insertion order, or TreeSet if you don't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+list+remove+duplicate ... or try similar search keys ... but at least, do some research first.

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem? If yes then you should mark one as accepted so the thread can be considered closed. If not, you can provide some feedback so a proper solution can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` (or any sort of `List`) is a suboptimal data structure for this problem as element lookup takes `O(n)` time where `n` is the size of the list. Basically you need to go through the whole list and check if that element is there:

```
public boolean contains(List<Employee> employees, Employee emp) {
    for(Employee el : employees) {
        if(el.equals(emp)) { // override equals() and hashCode() in Employee 
                             // or use a cutom equals(Employee, Employee) method
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Or with Java 8 syntax:

```
abc.stream().anyMatch(emp -> emp.equals(newEmployee));
```

If you can change that list to a `Set` then you can use the [contains(Element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method to check if the `Set` already contains a given element. Be aware that this method uses `equals` method to do the check!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to check for duplication, we can store the names in a set(**Set< String > names**), and check it every time before adding an employee to the list:

```
Employee[] obj = new Employee[n];
Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
...........
...........
if (!names.contains(nm) {
    abc.add(obj[i]);
    names.add(nm);
}
```